# About the physics engine

Tags: java-me, physics

is there any physics engine available for j2me as it is for symbian,iphone etc please send me the link or another source from where i can get the same reply asap. Thanks in advance everyone

Answer (score 7):

I invoked the [Google](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=physixs+engine+j2me) oracle which knows almost everything if asked the right question ;)

It found two engines:

[DyMix](http://dymix.hardwire.cz/), a 2d-j2me rigid body physics engine, 
and its cousin [Bloft](http://bloft.hardwire.cz/), a soft-body physics engine.
Do one of these suit your needs? What kind of physics are you interested in? Quantum state simulation, electrical simulation, rigid body simulation, kinematics, gravitational waves, ...?

**Update 1**
Since you are interested in motion, DyMix will probably be your friend. I have no experience to share with that library, but at least from its feature list, it seems as if it could help you.

quoted from the [first link](http://dymix.hardwire.cz/)

> Basic Features:
>
> - Rigid body dynamics
> - Flexible design, easy to implement
> - High control over the collision, exact collision points
> - Fast fixed-point calculations
> - Friction and restitution (bounce) simulation
> - Support for convex polygon shapes, segments and point-masses
> - Additional Vector2, Matrix2x2 classes and other math functions